# UIButton grouped Buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton

I'm trying to create a button set up exactly like this:

[image]

How would I do this? Can someone show me the code? Is there a way to "Group" UIButtons like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to use a `UITableViewController` with the sections set to be `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.

Each of the groups is a section, so you'll want to return how many sections you have with `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`.

For every section, you want to specify how many rows there are with `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`.

You'll want to customize each cell with `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` (which, by the way, tells you which section's particular row you're modifying in the `indexPath` variable).

Finally, you'll want to handle the row click in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, using the pattern XCode provides for you:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: To answer your question further, you can do this without having them be `UIButton`s. Just use a `UITableViewController` and have it respond to selecting cells.

Answer (score 1):

That's a one-group UITableView with two rows (cells).  The table style is UITableViewStyleGrouped.  I'd recommend responding to selection of the cell using the delegate's `–tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method as opposed to using UIButtons within the cell -- much nicer visual effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't group uibuttons like that. You can achieve this look-and-feel several ways, the most elegant is to use the grouped style uitableview. 
However if you would want your buttons only to look like this, but not exactly like this, then you could also specify images for you buttons. Uglier way to do it, however much simpler ...