# Button group in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I would like to create a button group in style with this in IOS.[image]

I have tried with a static uitableview but that did not work due to static cells has to be embedded directly within a tableviewcontroller and I want some text and other stuff in this view as well.

And if it is possible I would like to do this from the storyboard mostly. But if its not possible I can do it programmatically.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Actually this is `UITableView` with `UITableViewStyleGrouped` style: you can set that style even in IB.

Comment: @rokjarc yes it is, how can I add buttons to them so I can use it like a menu?

Comment: You're stil gonna have to write `dataSource` and `delegate` methods - those are the minimums for `UITableView` to _do it's job_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is with a `UITableView` with the style `UITableViewStyleGrouped`. See this question: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588370/uibutton-grouped-buttons).

Since you want more dynamic behavior, I'd recommend placing the `UITableView` in the storyboard, then making an outlet to your `UIViewController` subclass code. Make your `UIViewController` both a `<UITableViewDelegate>` and a `<UITableViewDataSource>`, and set the contents and behavior of your "buttons"(actually cells) programatically.

Comment: the problem with this is that I will loose the benefit of the storyboard visual linking, but it feels like this is the only way to do it

Comment: You can still create custom `UITableViewCell`s in IB (for each cell). Just a few lines of code have to be written. I think you're gonna like this [Custom UITableViewCell in IB](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/) tutorial.

Comment: If these buttons should trigger segues to other view controllers, you can set up "Manual" segues in the storyboard for the visual component and just trigger them programmatically.

Comment: @rokjarc Thanks but can I do this if I use the storyboard and not .xib files?

Comment: I never tried this with storyboards but it should work with some modifications. Also depends on what you want to do on "button tap". If button tap initiates moving to new view controller then check Joels comment.